# Pygame - window opens but fill() doesn't work and no events detected

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a simple pygame program (PyGame 1.9.6 on Python 3.7), but some of the code inside my while loop doesn't seem to work. When I run the program, the window opens, but the screen doesn't fill with black, nor does the window close when I press "x"

```
import pygame


# pygame setup
pygame.init()

# Open a window on the screen
width, height = 600, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

def main():
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    BLACK = (0,0,0)
    while running:
        clock.tick(5) # number of loops per second
        print("tick")
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print("event detected")

            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        pygame.display.update()


main()
```

In the console, "tick" appears like normal and "event detected" appears after pressing any keys or mouse click. I don't get any errors when I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If event == pygame.QUIT: should be if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

I usually use that event like this:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Telan said

```
if event==pygame.QUIT:
```

should be

```
if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
```

However to properly shutdown pygame, **pygame.quit()** is important to shutdown pygame modules which is the reverse of **pygame.init()**

While **sys.exit()** is used to properly shutdown the main python program.

```
from sys import exit
import pygame

if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    exit()
```

Full code is shown below. Enjoy!

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

# pygame setup
pygame.init()

# Open a window on the screen
width, height = 600, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    while True:
        clock.tick(5)  # number of loops per second
        print("tick")
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print("event detected")

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
                

        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```